# Debugging NGINX site config file

Tags: nginx

I'm having trouble setting up Nginx site configuration file.
So basically I'm serving 3 sites:

1. Dashboard `/dashboard` (react-based, operates at `xxx/xxx/build/index.html`)
2. API `/api` (node-based, operates using a proxy-pass and it works perfectly
3. Homepage `/` (static, operates at `xxx/yyy/zzz/index.html`)

My Nginx file looks as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/xxxxx;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/xxxxx;

  location /dashboard/ {
    root        /var/www/xxxxx/build;
    index        index.html;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
  location / {
    root        /var/www/xxxxxx;
    index       index.html;
    try_files   $uri /$uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

The problem lays mainly in the `/dashboard` path. For some reason it redirects to the homepage and never returns the actual dashboard.
I'm quite inexperienced in Nginx, so I'm not quite sure how to even debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess.

`root` will add your location `/dashbaord` behind `/var/www/xxxxx/build` like so:

```
/var/www/xxxxx/build/dashboard
```

That location does not exists so it tries `/index.php` at the end of `try_files` which is an "absolute path" to your homepage?

I would try using `alias` instead of `root` (which will not add `/dashboard` to your root path) and/or try to fix your last parameter in `try_files` like so:

```
try_files   $uri $uri/ ./index.html;
```